# Redirection problem while forward to sucess page

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

**I have a form. But when i am forwarding it to success page it is not validating forum and moving it to success page and below is my code. can some one please help me?**

Below is my detailed validation page and in the sucess page and below is my routing

```
 <Link to="/success">
     <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
         Submit
     </Button>
  </Link>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You usually validate either on change of a field (before you even submit) or on submit. If latter, you define your logic in the onSubmit function of the form:

```
export default function Form() {
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // do your validation here
    // conditionally do what you want
    // for example navigate to other page: 
    // history.push("/success");
  }
  return (
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        ...
        <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
      </Form>
  );
}
```

You don't need to wrap your Button with Link. Button with type="submit" automatically calls the onSubmit function of the form.

**Edit**: I have corrected your sandbox and now it's working: https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-curran-1hfe6j

I set the route to the form as "/" so it is initially shown when you load your app:

```
<Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<MyForm />} />
      <Route path="/success" element={<Success />} />
    </Routes>
```

- Your variables were not named the same in **initialValues**, **field'name** and **validate** function (name <-> username), I adjusted them

I have used *Form.Control.Feedback* to render error feedback in your form and set the *isInvalid* property in the *Form.Control*

```
<Form.Control
    ...
    isInvalid={!!formErrors.name}
/>
```

and

```
    <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
    {formErrors.name}
</Form.Control.Feedback>
```

Add *noValidate* property on your *Form* component, to prevent default HTML validation

```
<Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate className="p-3">
```

Validation is performed on submit, no compex useEffect hook needed

```
 const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const errors = validate(formValues);
    setFormErrors(errors);
    console.log(!errors);
    if (Object.keys(errors).length === 0) {
      navigate("success");
    }
  };
```